# Mysql Sql order before group by

Tags: mysql, sql

My Table As(users):

```
id    sdate                  ip

1     2016-03-19 22:43:52    88.234.15.68
2     2016-03-19 22:43:58    88.234.15.68
```

I want to short then group by. But I could not be successful. i can use this sql statement;

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY sdate DESC) as test 
GROUP BY test.ip 
ORDER BY sdate DESC
```

I get the following output:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY sdate DESC) as test 
GROUP BY test.ip 
ORDER BY sdate DESC

id    sdate                  ip

1     2016-03-19 22:43:52    88.234.15.68
```

i want to this output

```
id    sdate                  ip

2     2016-03-19 22:43:58    88.234.15.68
```

Comment: why you use `group by` without aggregate function like `MAX()` right now you get `test.ip` and a random value for the rest of columns

Comment: Sorry but your question isnt clear. Include details of your logic, right now several query will generate same result.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear. The OP wants to first `order by`, then `group by`.

Comment: @Jacco The question isnt clear  because not matter if data is order or not. The `group by` wont be any different. As I explain the group by without aggregation will produce random values.

Comment: So Goksel explain what logic you want use to select the output row and we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, you could try this query:

```
SELECT      t1.*
    FROM    users t1
    JOIN    (
        SELECT      MAX(t.sdate) as sdate,
                    t.ip
            FROM    users t
        GROUP BY    t.ip
            ) t2
        ON  t2.sdate = t1.sdate
        AND t2.ip = t1.ip
  ORDER BY  t1.sdate DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the id for JOIN

```
SELECT u1.*, u2.*
FROM (
  SELECT max(id) AS id FROM `users` GROUP BY ip
  ) AS u1
LEFT JOIN `users` u2 ON u1.id  = u2.id;
```